# Theorem to show $(m+n)^2$ is even implies $m+n$ is even

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I understand that

$\begin{align*}
(m+n)^2 &= (m+n)(m+n) = m^2+2mn+n^2\\
&\implies m^2+n^2 = (m+n)^2-2mn\\
&\implies (m+n)^2 = 2k+2mn = 2(k+mn)\\
&\implies m+n\text{ is even}?
 \end{align*}$

I  don't understand how the proof exactly or maybe i copied it wrong

Comment: That's just an obfuscated way to state that if $\,a^2\,$ is even then $\,a\,$ is even. Can you show that?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: oh really? and yeah i can

Comment: Yeah is if $a = m+n$ and $a^2 = (m+n)^2$ then $a$ is even, right.  So $a = m+n$ is even and... nothing to do.

Comment: I think the proof is trying to do something clever but I don't know what.  So far it proves that $(m+n)^2$ is even implies $m^2 + n^2 = (m+n)^2 -2mn$ is even... and I don't know what it intends to do after that.  If this was the supposed proof they are definitely taking an indirect route probably to show something clever.  The easy way is simply.  If $m+n$ is odd then $(m+n)^2$ is odd and if $m+n$ is even then $(m+n)^2$ is even.  So... conversely if $(m+2)^2$ the only option left is $m + n$ is even.